# Substracting column values that satisfy a condition from constant value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate heating degree days.I have the following dataframe:

```
df.head()
Out[196]: 
           NUTS_ID        t2m
Date                         
2010-01-01    AT11   4.134250
2010-07-01    AT11  24.019817
2010-07-01    AT12  21.902833
2010-01-01    AT12   2.687778
2010-01-01    AT13   3.796989
```

I want to substract all the temperatures in column `t2m` from 18 if they are below this number, and assign 0 to the columns where t2m is over 18. That is,

```
           NUTS_ID        t2m                  HDD
Date                                              
2010-01-01    AT11   4.134250            13.865750
2010-07-01    AT11  24.019817                    0
2010-07-01    AT12  21.902833                    0
2010-01-01    AT12   2.687778            15.312222
2010-01-01    AT13   3.796989            14.203011
```

I tried doing

```
df.loc[df['t2m']<18,'HDD']=18-df['t2m']
df.loc[df['t2m']>18,'HDD']=0
```

But I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` (and possibly in the first line I would be affecting the values of the rows higher than 18 anyway). How could I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good and efficient way is to use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['HDD'] = np.where(df['t2m'] > 18,0,18 - df['t2m'])

Out[97]: 
        Date NUTS_ID   t2m   HDD
0 2010-01-01    AT11  4.13 13.87
1 2010-07-01    AT11 24.02  0.00
2 2010-07-01    AT12 21.90  0.00
3 2010-01-01    AT12  2.69 15.31
4 2010-01-01    AT13  3.80 14.20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html#pandas-dataframe-clip):

```
>>> df['HDD'] = (18 - df.t2m).clip(lower=0)
           NUTS_ID        t2m        HDD
Date                                    
2010-01-01    AT11   4.134250  13.865750
2010-07-01    AT11  24.019817   0.000000
2010-07-01    AT12  21.902833   0.000000
2010-01-01    AT12   2.687778  15.312222
2010-01-01    AT13   3.796989  14.203011
```